# How to find out position of a point, given a vector, projection on the vector, and angle.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

I need to find the position of a point `q` given a vector $\vec{se}$, projection of `q` on $\vec{se}$, and angle $\theta$ between $\vec{se}$ and $\vec{eq}$.

[image]

Known are `s(s1, s2, s3)`, `e(e1, e2, e3)`, `p(p1, p2, p3)`, and `theta`. Is there a way to find out `q(q1, q2, q3)`, such that $ep$ is projection of $\vec{eq}$?

We know:

1. $\vec{se}.\vec{pq} = 0$
2. $|\vec{eq}|cos(\theta) = |\vec{ep}|$

However, we need another equation to solve for `q(q1, q2, q3)`. Is there some way to deal with this?

Additional Info: I am trying to generate an arrow head around $e$, given `s(s1, s2, s3)`, and `e(e1, e2, e3)`. As a newbie I thought this step by step approach will be easy, and now I am stuck here.

Comment: $\theta,s,e$ and the dot product are not enough to determine $q$. That just restricts it to lie on a circle. If one position works, you can rotate it around the line $se$ and every point on the circle works.

Comment: @almagest Thank you for your comment. I also had thought that, and then I thought to ask the question here to get help from more experienced members than me :)